# C# - Scanning a list of names then getting its index

Tags: c#, list, indexing

I have a list of strings, which i used to store some names, what i want now is to ask for user to input a name and check if that name is in the list and then get the index of that name.
I'm still pretty new to C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IndexOf` (a member of `List<T>`) [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int index = myList.IndexOf(enteredString);
```

It will return -1 if no match is found. You may want to convert the list and input to lowercase if you need to deal with case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [List.IndexOf Method (T) (From MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The zero-based index of the first occurrence of item within the entire List, if found; otherwise, –1.
>
> ...
>
> This method determines equality using the default equality comparer EqualityComparer.Default for T, the type of values in the list.

See the following example:

```
List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>()
    {
        "test1", // index of 0
        "test2", // index of 1
        "test3", // index of 2
        "test4", // index of 3
        "test5", // index of 4
        "test6", // index of 5
        "test7", // index of 6
        "test8", // index of 7
        "test9", // index of 8
        "test10" // index of 9
    };

int index = listOfStrings.IndexOf("test6"); //should return 5
```